# Chrome Firebug to take up window space

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firebug

So in the Chrome version of Firebug, it's lying on top of the window, thus, if the whole window has text, you will have stuff hidden behind the firebug. Is it possible to get it to be like Firefox's version, where it is part of the window screen like the developer console? The options don't seem to point to anything that indicates this option.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome extension of Firebug is based on Firebug Lite, which is a JavaScript that is injected into the website. So, there is unfortunately no way to integrate it into Chrome's UI.

Furthermore, Firebug Lite (and with that the Chrome extension) is unmaintained for several years now, so it doesn't provide the features integrated developer tools have.

Alternatives are:

## Chrome DevTools

Chrome has [integrated developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), which provide a huge amount of features for web developers.

## Firefox DevTools

The [Firefox developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) allow to [debug Chrome (and other browsers) remotely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging). This doesn't work as good as the integrated tools and provides less features, but allows you to use the same tools to debug in different browsers.

## debugger.html

The [debugger.html project](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html) (developed by the Firefox DevTools team) picks up the idea of Firebug Lite by providing a browser independent UI. It's based on a local web server serving a website, which allows you to debug JavaScript code in different browsers by connecting to them remotely. Unfortunately, it currently only provides a JavaScript debugger and it's unclear whether it will be extended to cover other features like an HTML inspector panel, a network panel, etc. later.

Comment: The main thing I need from firebug is when you post/get to backend sources e.g. php, you can view the responses. Is there such a feature in the DevTools, because I can't seem to find them.

Comment: The requests are displayed within the [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) and also within the [Web Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) when you have the related filter enabled.